# Toggle a Div, with a variable width, horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery

This could be hard to explain.

I am using the code below too toggle a div partially out of the window horizontally and back in again. This works, but I have a problem or two.

The div I am toggling has a variable width according to the window width (vw), and not for each window width are the number of vw units the same. This is controlled by media queries for different window widths.

This causes a problem, as when the div is toggled to be partially off window and I scale the window, the amount of div visible in screen changes, which I don’t want. Plus when I toggle the div fully back in screen the width is not in accordance with the media query for the window size.

What I want to have happen is to toggle the the div off window always leaving the same amount of div left in window regardless of the window size. Plus when I toggle the div back in screen that the div takes on the width in accordance with the media query for the window size as it is at that moment.

So:
    When toggled out of view (partially) I want the div to continue to scale with window width changes according to the media queries. But even then I want the div to only show 80 pixels within the window. When the div is toggled in full view again it will then have the correct width according to the media queries settings.

Perhaps this:
It seems like the div needs a right alignment when toggled partially off window. So if the window is scaled, the consequent changing of  the div width size does not affect how it appears in the window. It then stays at 80 px, because the div will get smaller or larger off window. But when the div is toggled to appear fully in screen again it needs to align left to the window again. Could this work somehow and how would this be coded?

The [**JSFIDDLE Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/100pvu95/30/). Can anyone help please?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#togglebutton").click(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){

        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
                left: '0%'
        });
        }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
                left: -$('#myToggleDiv').width() + 80
        });
        }


        });
    });
```

Comment: using a scalable unit AND media queries is redundant. switch to pixels. you don't need vw if you're using media queries anyway..

Comment: But if I want a vw variable width within a certain range of window sizes I need VW units don't I?

Comment: In the JSFIDDLE you can see the I have set 80 vw, 90 vw , and 100 vw within different window size ranges. So the vw amount is not the same across all window sizes.

Comment: right, but if you have  a media query to set it to (for example) 10vw when the viewport is 100pixels wide, that is exactly the same thing as having it set to 10px. isince youre using media queries you can easily just do a little math to convert the vw into pixels.

Comment: I could be figuring this wrong, but if I set a div width of 10vw for a window size range 1000 - 2000 pixels, it will not be the same amount of pixel width for the div every time the window is scaled within the 1000 to 2000 pixel range. Therefore I am using vw. I cannot use pixel width for the div as it then will not be responsive within the window size range between 1000 to 2000 pixels.

Comment: i must have misunderstood your question because i thought that was the problem.. you don't want the size to change when it's scaled.. correct?

Comment: I know you're currently doing this with js, but it might be a candidate for css `calc()` i.e. `right: calc(100vw - 80px)` will always stick the element 80px into the frame no matter what the viewport size. Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: seconded... if browser support isn't super important, jesse's idea will work perfectly..

Comment: yes. thanks. Let me try to figure out how to apply this, unless you care to adapt my JFFIDDLE.

Comment: browser compatibility is very important.

Comment: When toggled out of view (partially) I want the div to continue to scale with window width changes according to the media queries. But even then I want the div to only show 80 pixels within the window. When the div is toggled in full view again it will then have the correct width according to the media queries settings.

Comment: Maybe a float or align right needs to be added to the div when out of view, and float or align right needs to added when the div is in full view? How?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an adjustment to the margin of 80px, and using a width of 100% for the positioning?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#togglebutton").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

          $(this).removeClass('active');
          $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
            left: '0%',
            'margin-left': '0'
          });
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('active');
          $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
            left: '-100%',
            'margin-left': '80px'
        });
    }


  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, This seems to work at first. But after the div is toggled to 80px, and then the window is scaled to a large size, the div disappears totally off window. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/100pvu95/32/

Comment: It seems like the div needs a right alignment when toggled partially off window. So if the window is scaled, the consequent changing of  the div width size does not affect how it appears in the window. It then stays at 80 px, because the div will get smaller or larger off window. But when the div is toggled to appear fully in screen again it needs to align left to the window again. Could this work somehow and how would this be coded?

Comment: Did you hear about `display:flex`? If yes, use it. If not - google it. And then delete these media queries. They are not necessary.